# PySpark group by collect_list over a window

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame with multiple columns. I'm trying to aggregate few columns using collect_list grouped on id, over a window function. I'm trying some thing like this:

```
exprs = [(collect_list(x).over(window)).alias(f"{x}_list") for x in cols]
df = df.groupBy('id').agg(*exprs)
```

I'm getting the below error:

> expression is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get

If I do the same for a single column, instead of for multiple columns it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way for this. I guess, window functions wont work for `agg(*exprs)` operations. So, I modified the above to

```
for col_name in cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col_name + "_list", collect_list(col(col_name)).over(window_spec))
```

This served my purpose.

Thank you.